# How to open browser print window with Vaadin BrowserFrame

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I would like the PDF to open immediately to the browser's print window rather than the BrowserFrame in Vaadin. Right now my code is:

```
Window window = new Window();

StreamResource streamResource = getPdfAsStream();
streamResource.setMIMEType("application/pdf");

BrowserFrame browserFrame = new BrowserFrame("PDF File", streamResource);
browserFrame.setId("pdfToPrintBrowserFrame");

window.setContent(browserFrame);
UI.getCurrent().addWindow(window);
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(
    "document.getElementById('pdfToPrintBrowserFrame').contentWindow.print();");
```

This code doesn't work but in essence I'd like to call the browser's print through Javascript on the pdf. How can this be done?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I want the exact same thing.

Comment: I'll answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found two options:

The first is to use an iFrame:

```
StreamRegistration registration = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getResourceRegistry().registerResource(streamResource);
IFrame iframe = new IFrame(registration.getResourceUri().toString());
// Setting the width to 100% results in a scrollbar for some reason and I cannot find a way to remove it. 
iframe.setHeight("95%");
iframe.setWidthFull();

DialogWithCloseButton dialog = new DialogWithCloseButton();
dialog.setWidth("80%");
dialog.setHeight("90%");
dialog.open();
dialog.add(iframe);
```

The other option which I like a lot is to use the Pdf Viewer add-on from the Vaadin directory which can be found at: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/pdf-viewer

I found the second option (the pdf viewer component) to be the better option for me. It's a lot richer. The only thing is that it may be more than you want.

Also I remember something about printing more than once but it's been a while so it could be something or it could be nothing. If the printing fails on the second attempt then there may be something that needs to be done, I just don't remember what.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Your solution looks really neat! Unfortunately I'm using Vaadin 8 (upgrade is, unfortunately, not an option), where `StreamRegistration` and `IFrame` does not seem to exist. I'm currently trying some of the methods [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-printing#advanced.printing.opening).